# apache is up but does not read requests

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd, netstat

This usually happens a few minutes after restarting `apache`:

`httpd` daemons are up, but are not reading the requests from the sockets. The web clients just wait forever on the connection.

When I run `netstat`, the Recv-Qs are showing a positive byte count which does not change. So basically the connection between the client and apache is in the CONNECTED state but no progress is made.

Restarting apache solves the problem for a couple of minutes, but then it's deja vu all over again.

Other servers (`sshd`, `ftpd`, etc) are fine.

Where should I look further? Any clue? Thanks!

Comment: Can you post your apache logs?

Comment: Try attaching to the process and see what it does with strace -p pid

Answer (score 1):

Run "netstat -l" to verify apache is on actively listening on port 80, then verify there isn't a firewall in the network path interfering with traffic, either on the localhost ("iptables -L") or on the network.

It also wouldn't be a bad idea to check the selinux logs if you have that enabled.

Answer (score 1):

how many apache processes are running when this happen? If you are getting hammered which too many requests apache will seem to just hang.

Answer (score 1):

Please post your httpd.conf as well as a your trasnfer log and error log which will help in diagnosing this.  Are you setting a timeout in httpd.conf? http://www.faqs.org/docs/securing/chap29sec245.html

What type of file is being requested?  Does this occur when hosting a static HTML file?